# How to return string value with .wrap and cypress command feature

Tags: typescript, string, automated-tests, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I have a code :

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getLabelText', (parentSelector: string, label: string) => {
  var result: string= '';
  cy.get(parentSelector).within(() => {
    cy.get(`[aria-label="${label}"]`).then(el => {
      result.replace(el.text(), '')
    })
    return cy.wrap(result)
  })
})
```

I have tried many different ways to assign new value to string, this example is just one of those.

I want to return element text and use it like :

```
 verifyText: () => {
    cy.getLabelText(locator, expectedString).then(value => {
      expect(value).to.eq(expectedString)
    })
  },
```

Cypress will return locatro insted of text:

```
expected '<div.v-data-table.summary-table.v-data-table--dense.v-data-table--fixed-height.theme--light>' to equal 'expectedString'
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `cy.wrap()` the last action in the chain. No need to `return` since you are accessing the last subject on the chain with `.then(value =>`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getLabelText', (parentSelector, label) => {
  let result = '';
  cy.get(parentSelector).within(() => {
    cy.get(`[aria-label="${label}"]`).then(el => {
      result = el.text()
    })
  }).then(() => {
    cy.wrap(result)
  })
})
```

Comment: Thats it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to return the value, you will have to return the entire chain.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getLabelText', (parentSelector: string, label: string) => {
  return cy.get(parentSelector).within(() => {
    return cy.get(`[aria-label="${label}"]`).then(el => {
      return el;
    })
  })
})

...
 verifyText: () => {
    cy.getLabelText(locator, expectedString).then(el => {
      expect(el.text()).to.eq(expectedString)
    })
  }
```

Additionally, if your `expectedString` will always be the same for the function and the assertion using the result of the function, you can just assert in the function.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getLabelText', (parentSelector: string, label: string) => {
  cy.get(parentSelector).within(() => {
   cy.get(`[aria-label="${label}"]`).then(el => {
      expect(el.text()).to.eq(label);
    })
  })
})
...
 verifyText: () => {
    cy.getLabelText(locator, expectedString);
  }
```

Comment: `.within() yields the same subject it was given from the previous command.`
So I doubt if `return cy.get(parentSelector).within` could work here

Answer (score 0):

If the aria-label matchs the text content,

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getLabelText', (parentSelector: string, label: string) => {

  const selector = `${parentSelector} [aria-label="${label}"]`;

  cy.get(selector)
    .invoke('text')        // this text is returned
    .should('eq', label)
  })
})

cy.getLabelText(locator, expectedString)
  .then(value => {
    expect(value).to.eq(expectedString)
  })
```